# typescript anonymous nested types

Tags: typescript

given the following type:

```
type Foo = {
  a: {
    b: number
    c: string
  }
  d: number
}
```

is there a way to retrieve the anonymous nested types? I was thinking something like `TypeOf<Foo, 'a'>` should return the type made of b and c and `TypeOf<Foo, 'd'>` should be an alias to number. I made up the syntax, but I wanted to know if a similar concept exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out you can do this by doing `Foo['a']`. Great!

Comment: If you're going to reuse the inner type, you should make a real type for clarity

Comment: that's not always possible. In my case this type comes from a code generator, so I am stuck with that. I still don't know how to handle complex cases like if `a` is optional, then `Foo['a']['b']` will throw, do you know how to address this?

Comment: No, I had not even heard of this solution you found